# Japanese characters are converted to '\0" when entering commands in powershell

Tags: c#, command-line, .net-core, command-line-arguments

I am working on making my own music player, and right now it has no GUI. I use a "load" command to load new songs for playing, and my problem is this:

When I write `"load Timelineの東.wav`" it *gets corrupted* and the song title becomes `"Timeline\0\0.wav"`.
I'm using **Windows PowerShell** with the

> "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support."

that can be accessed from running "**intl.cpl**" and pressing the "**Change system locale**" button.

I am also using the "**NSimSum**" font, which has no problem displaying the Japanese characters.

Comment: This question is marked `.net-core`, but are you actually using PowerShell Core (aka PowerShell 6+) or "classic" PowerShell (<6)? I suspect that might make some difference in how things work. (Specifically, I can copy-paste `"load Timelineの東.wav"` into PowerShell Core with no issues whatsoever, having *not* used the UTF-8 option in `intl.cpl`, however.)

Comment: What's more, if I do `chcp 65001` in PowerShell classic (to switch the console to UTF-8, which is not the default there) I can copy-paste `"load Timelineの東.wav"` into it. The characters are corrupted to `??` for display on the command line, but the printed output is actually correct, and the characters have their correct Unicode values when inspected with `[int] "の東.wav"[0]`.

Comment: Apparently I am using Version 5.1 of PowerShell. I will upgrade to PowerShell Core and report back

Comment: I've read that doing "chcp 65001" is generally not advised, apparently there are numerous bugs / oddities that comes with it, though some of them were fixed in a win 10 update. But because of this I do not want to rely on chcp 65001

Comment: `chcp 65001` only affects the console (terminal) process anyway, not PowerShell per se. PowerShell itself is a Unicode process (as it's .NET at heart, which is fully Unicode), so any difficulties in getting strings into it or out of it are generally external. The PowerShell ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment) also has no problem handling Unicode strings, as it does not need to rely on the console.

Comment: I have tried using PowerShell Core, unfortunately it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Then you might need to be more specific about what you're doing when you say you "write" a string, and/or test with the system-wide UTF-8 option disabled. Copy-pasting your string into a console works fine for me (W10 18362.356).

Comment: When I run my program and enter `load Timelineの東.wav` it gets stored in a string using the Console.ReadLine() function like this:
`input = Console.ReadLine();`
When I inspect the `input` string in debug, the Japanese characters have been replaced with '\0'

Comment: I have now tried using `chcp 65001`. Unfortunately that too did not work

Comment: You mean the string is read incorrectly from the console in a C# program, right? That may not have anything to do with PowerShell at all. Do you get the same results if the program is started from `cmd`? What's the value of `Console.InputEncoding` inside the program, and do things improve if you explicitly set that to `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: Yes! That was what I had to do! Thanks for your help! If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll go ahead and mark it, if not I can answer it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeroen Mostert pointed out in the comments of my question. Changing the value of `Console.InputEncoding` to `Encoding.UTF8` solved my problem